# Partially zip files in a directory and move to pCloud account

Tags: zip

I have a 60GB directory, including thousands of files with random names and file extensions, but no sub-directories.

Since I only have 12 GB of free space left, I need to partially zip this directory's content and transfer them one by one.

Is it possible to zip the first 10GB of files inside this directory, and once it is transferred to somewhere else, proceed with the next 10GB of files? Or maybe zipping files with a sequence. e.g.:

- Zip `file#1` to `file#10000` ===> `1-10000.zip`
- Transfer and remove from source directory
- Then, zip `file#10000` to `file#20000` ====> `10000-20000.zip`
- and so on

It's an Ubuntu VPS and I have ~12 GB free space left on the disk. My VPS provider cannot extend the disk. So, I want to transfer the zip files to my pCloud account. I already tried `rclone` but it takes days to transfer all the files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly what you wanted, but:

```bsh
zip -m -s 10g -sp -sb -r -j /other-dir/my-split-archive.zip /my-dir-with-files
```

will start creating a split archive in parts, 10 GB each in size, pausing (and maybe beeping) after each part to let you transfer it away before proceeeding, deleting source files after completion.

Comment: Thanks. Interesting solution! I'll try.